# Как написать программу которая после запуска будет запускать отсчет времени?

Tags: python

Нужно создать программу, которая после запуска будет выводить текст "Осталось времени: 5 секунд" и с каждой секундой текст должен менять время на 1 секунду.

Comment: Тяжело помочь разобраться, если разбираться не в чем - вы же свой код не приложили к вопросу.

Comment: например использовать time.sleep(1) что бы приостановить выполнение на 1 секунду. И так в цикле

Comment: вам предоставили много ответов. Выберите пожалуйста ответ, который отвечает на ваш вопрос и отметьте его как правильный. Если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Печатает строку и засыпает на секунду

```
import time
k = 5
while k != 0:
    print("Осталось времени: {} секунд".format(k))
    k -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, должно помочь.

```
import time

waitingTime = 5

while True:
    time.sleep(waitingTime / waitingTime)
    waitingTime -= 1
    print("Осталось времени: " + str(waitingTime))
    if waitingTime == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Зачем такая "сложная" математика, чтобы получить 1?

Comment: Это просто мой пример:)

Comment: Ну если это просто пример как не нужно делать, то ок.

Comment: Но ведь работает же!

Comment: Не всегда, правда :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLCDNumber,
                            QSpinBox, QGridLayout, QApplication)
import threading


class Window(QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):      
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.button = QPushButton("Начать обратный отсчет")
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.spin = QSpinBox(self)
        
        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.lcd)
        grid.addWidget(self.spin)
        grid.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.initUI()
     
    def initUI(self):
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.timing)
       
    def timing(self):
        self.tbutton1 = threading.Thread(target=self.timingThread, daemon=True)
        self.tbutton1.start()
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        
    def timingThread(self):        
        timing = self.spin.value()
        for i in range(timing, -1, -1):
            QThread.msleep(1000)
            self.lcd.display("{}".format(i))
        self.button.setEnabled(True)             
       
        
if __name__=='__main__':       
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.resize(300, 200)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]